# Identify key independent variable in Multiple Regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models

I am a newbie to this technique and much grateful if there are any advice on the norm of practicing multiple regression on the following questions as below:

1. I need to identify key independent variables(predictors) in total 12, which of them are the significant contributor to a problem: e.g customer is not purchasing due to etc..
   hence, I was recommended to use multiple regression to do the identification.
   Is multiple regression the only technique to resolve it?
2. I have 12 independent variables, which 6 of them are categorical and another 6 of them are continuous numbers. The categorical variables are nationalities, locations, membership type etc. After recoding them into 1,2, etc into groups, is there a need to standardize these categorical variables with the continuous variables? if yes, is there a good method to standardize them beside doing log?
3. To use for multiple regression, do we need to check every variables that they are normal distributed?

Comment: I think an introductory textbook on regression would more helpful at this stage. Some of these questions have pretty standard answers. So, I recommend starting with an introductory textbook and then asking specific questions about multiple regression as you proceed. There is a fair chance that some of the questions you might have were already asked.  So, checking specific tags (and their wiki) will be a better strategy. Also, since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.